# Centre fixed width div in between two divs of the same width that stretch to the edge of the screen

Tags: css, css-position

I need to have 3 `<div>` near each other. The middle one, with a fixed width of 1048px needs to be perfectly centred and also stretch till the bottom. I also have a header.

I also need to put 2 `<div>` on each side, to stretch to the bottom, because I need to have some content there, but they need to adjust their size accordingly to the screen size. So the width of each of these needs to be (screen width - 1048px) / 2.

I have put a JSFiddle example here (the width here is 600px just to show the effect in the small JSFiddle window).

http://jsfiddle.net/mY2bw/

As you can see the Left Side and Right Side are not displaying on each side and taking the full width.

Is there a clean way to achieve this in CSS?

**UPDATE**

Its important that both the side `<div>`s and the center `<div>` stretch to the bottom because I need to put some background images to them.

I also need to put a sticky footer at the bottom, so whatever solution is suggested also needs to be compatible with that.

Comment: Can you use Sass, and do you care about IE 8?

Comment: On another note, I would suggest using classes instead of id's - and putting border-box on * {everything}

Comment: Well not sure about IE8, sometimes these clients have these obsolete browsers on their systems. How would I go about it with SASS? I've never used it. (If its something heavy ideally I don't introduce it just for this)

Comment: Still I don't see your point. I've clearly asked for a CSS solution to a small problem and you're suggesting to change to a completely different framework just to solve it, without even saying how it would solve my issue. Its like asking how do I do a function in Javascript and you come saying you should use Python.

Comment: Determining if you need IE determines if you can use calc(); for math - which would help you. If you are writing in Sass, then I would do the math differently. But - anyways, Good Luck!

Comment: OK, you might want to suggest a SASS-based answer. It might be useful for people looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/8DKzK/)**</kbd>

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
         <h1>Fixed Width Center Column - Fluid sides</h1>   
    </div>
    <div id="innerwrap">
        <div id="left">
            <div id="inner-left">
                <p>Left fluid column content.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="center">
            <p>This layout is constructed using 2 floats of (100% - 1024px)/2 each.</div>
        <div id="right">
            <div id="inner-right">
                <p>Right fluid column content.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end innerwrap-->
    <div id="center-faux"></div>
</div>
<!--end wrapper-->
<div id="footer">
     <h3>Footer</h3>
</div>
```

css

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
body:before {
    /*Opera Fix*/
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-bottom:-100px;
    /*header height*/
}
html, body {
    height:100%;
    background:#BBB;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    /*footer soak up*/
    position:relative;
    /*set as containing block for AP faux column*/
}
#innerwrap {
    /*IE6 needs this for the AP faux column*/
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#header {
    border-top:50px solid #333;
    /*footer soak up*/
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    /*layer it above the AP faux*/
    background:#333;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    min-width: 1024px;
}
#left {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:-512px;
    /*background:#fff; for visual testing*/
}
#inner-left {
    margin-right:512px;
    background:#BBB;
    /*same as body BG*/
}
#center {
    width:1024px;
    float:left;
    background:#FFF;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
}
#right {
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    margin-left:-512px;
}
#inner-right {
    margin-left:512px;
    background:#BBB;
    /*same as body BG*/
}
#center-faux {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1024px;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: 0;
}
* html #center-faux {
    height:999em
}
/*for IE6*/
 #footer {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:#333;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    min-width: 1024px;
}
P {
    padding:10px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite work for me. The side `<div>`s and the center `<div>` does not stretch to the bottom as in my original. So I can't do background textures etc.

Comment: can you put your code here, then I can help you even better. or try to fiddle it...:)

Comment: My original code is already in a fiddle in my question. You can see the problem I am talking about quite easily on yours by changing the background colours of the sides. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/8DKzK/1/  I need the grey and red parts to stretch to the bottom.

Comment: The left and right sides are still not stretching to the bottom. You are just setting the body background to their same background to hide it, but they are not stretching to the bottom. It becomes evident the moment I set the background colours to different ones: http://jsfiddle.net/8DKzK/6/